# how to install dotnet framework+Windows installer 3.0 using VS2005 setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

i have included DotnetFramework, Windows installer in VS Setup Project through
Setup Project ->properties

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3158/prerequisite.jpg](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/3158/prerequisite.jpg)

but while run setup.msi it ask me to download dotnet framework from online

i would like to eliminate the process, it should be run from local folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found one solution [DotnetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com), which is perfectly worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the actual .NET framework file in your installer then.

The properties page simply lists dependencies, but does not actually include them.

Comment: ok, but i have dotnetframework & windows installer in relevant folder, even though it goes to online to download

Comment: is there any possible way to include required files in to single msi file

Comment: how do i launch dotnetfx.exe if framework not installed and also windows installer 3.1

Comment: There should be an option to pack all the relevant files in.